# Basic Dict manipulation in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dict,

```
D = {
    'outermost': {
        'inner': {
            'key1': '', 
            'key2': '', 
            'key3': '', 
            'key4': '', 
            'key5': ''
        }
    }
}
```

a list,

```
L = ['outermost', 'inner']
```

and a string,

```
K = 'key1'
```

and a value,

```
V = 'add a value'
```

How can I get a **output** like this

```
D = {
    'outermost': {
        'inner': {
            'key1': 'add a value', 
            'key2': '', 
            'key3': '', 
            'key4': '', 
            'key5': ''
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to modify the dict?

Comment: `D[L[0]][L[1]][K] = V`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `reduce` and `operator.getitem`:

```
from operator import getitem
reduce(getitem, L, D)[K] = V
```

**Output:**

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(D)
{'outermost': {'inner': {'key1': 'add a value',
                         'key2': '',
                         'key3': '',
                         'key4': '',
                         'key5': ''}}}
```

Comment: That, dear sir, is as pythonic as it gets.

Comment: So "pythonic" that Guido removed `reduce` as a builtin as being awfully un-pythonic. :P

Comment: -0.  Doesn't seem pythonic to me -- more like overkill.

Comment: Guido removed `reduce` for USUALLY being unpythonic.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
# Will raise a KeyError if the path does not exist.
def set_dict_path(dct, path, key, value):
    for p in path:
        dct = dct[p]

    dct[key] = value

set_dict_path(D, L, K, V)
```